# Dynamically adding items to Packery. How does it work exactly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-masonry, jquery-isotope, packery

I want to append ajax returned items to Packery, remove the current items and layout the new ones.

I have it working on codepen with a forked pen from Metafizzy (the developer)

This is the exact functionality i want: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Cnbxu/

However, in my code case I don't have to create the items array or add it to the DOM since I'm working with an element array that's already created.

Here's a sample of the code I'm using.

```
$.post( ajax_vars.ajaxurl, { action: 'function', param : param }, function(data){

    if( data == '' || data == 'undefined' || data == 'No More Posts' || data == 'No $args array created' ){
        data = '';
    }      
    //gather current Packery elements
    var elToRemove = pckry.getItemElements()
    // append elements to container
    container.append($(data));
        console.log(elems);
    // add and lay out newly appended elements
    pckry.addItems($(data));

    pckry.remove(elToRemove);
    packery.layout();
      elems = pckry.getItemElements();
    console.log(elems);

    }
});
```

The elements are there, console.log($(data)) shows the response and when I check the Inspector I can see the returned elements inside the container div. The problem is that no matter what I do I can't get Packery to 'recognize' the new items and layout them accordingly. elems returns empty. I've used the addItems(), preppended() and appended() methods with no avail.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you first need to call append, then after that call appended, very tricky.

here is how i got it to work

```
    var elems = [];
    var elem = document.createElement('div');
    elem.innerHTML = "<img src='http://placehold.it/1000X500'></div>"
    elem.className = 'item'
    //add your element to the arrays, you can add multiple here
    elems.push(elem)
    // append elements to container
    container.append(elems);
    // add and lay out newly appended elements
    container.packery('appended', elems);
```